# Localization to Spanish not working in wso2 api manager

Tags: localization, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Followed instructions on:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Internationalization+and+Localization

Trying this on google chrome and firefox. Changed the language to spanish, but wso2 does not pick up locale_es.json and still displays english.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you must ensure the locale_es.json file is well-formed (the original one it is not) and has the correct translates. 
Then modify 'language' parameters from 'en' to 'es' in the .pot files and the dynamic.po